# How to reslove instrumentation error in selendroid?

Tags: selendroid

I have given following coding to start android device.While running,it points the android device and it creates the Android driver App in android device,after that it throws the following error message.

```
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(DesiredCapabilities.android());
driver.get("url");
```

Error message:

```
     Failed tests:   setUp(mobileweb.photocentric.ScrollArticleTest): Could not start the app under test using instrumentation.
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{io.selendroid.io.selendroid.androiddriver/io.selendroid.server.ServerInstrumentation}
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: io.selendroid.io.selendroid.androiddriver/io.selendroid.server.ServerInstrumentation
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.runInstrument(Am.java:865)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:282)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found out that the androiddriver package was conflicting with a previous version installed in my device.

Try uninstalling the package from your device with the following command:

```
adb shell pm uninstall io.selendroid.io.selendroid.androiddriver
```

Comment: That did the trick for me after upgrading from 0.12 to 0.14! Thx